# How to open a directory of current buffer that is opening a file using just one command in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, directory, command

Is there any simple command to do this? I'm tired to type `C-x C-f ENTER`.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean opening current directory in `dired`?

Comment: I want to do "C-x C-f ENTER"(run find-file command then enter) in one command. If there is no simple command, I'll use keyboard macro. Sorry for my English skill. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! I have posted an answer let me know if that is what you wanted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you `(require 'dired-x)` in your init file (or alternatively follow the autoloading instructions<sup>1</sup>), you can use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> to call `dired-jump`, which not only does what you want (in both file-visiting buffers and also in dired buffers), but also places point on the dired entry for the file or directory that you have just come from, which can be incredibly convenient.

<sup>1</sup> <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(dired-x) Optional Installation Dired Jump` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Wow this is very cool. I think it is more useful than @Iqbal Ansari answer.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a single command to do that as far as I know, but since you are using emacs you can easily define one. Add these to your `init` file

```
(defun my-open-dired-here ()
  (interactive)
  (dired default-directory))
```

The above defines a command to open `dired` in current buffer's directory, this is what you get when you do `C-x C-f RET` in vanilla emacs.

You can bind the above command to a key of your choice I am binding it to <kbd>F6</kbd>

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f6>") 'my-open-dired-here)
```

Now when you press <kbd>F6</kbd> you will get dired opened in current buffer's directory.

Comment: Oh that's what I wanted. It's really simple. Thanks!!

Comment: I found @phils answer is more useful. So I moved the check mark. Sorry.